# Prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Could you tell me why prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ are of the form $(q(x))$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

1) Because $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is a PID (in fact, even an Euclidean domain) and thus all its ideals are principal.

2) Becasue in $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ , a non zero ideal is prime iff it is maximal (this is *far* from being true in general rings, though).

3) Finally, because a principal ideal (in this cases) is prime iff it is generated by a prime element, and in the ring of polynomials an element is prime iff it is irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of a general theorem that states: $R[x]$ is a PID
when $R$ is a field

Here we have $R=\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

A proof for this can be found for example at [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Polynomial_Forms_over_Field_form_Principal_Ideal_Domain)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $F$ is a field and $I$ is a non-zero ideal in $F[x]$, and $g(x)$ is an element of $F[x]$. Then, $I=\langle g(x)\rangle$ **iff** $g(x)$ is a non-zero polynimial of minimum degree in $I$.

And $g(x)$ is irreducible iff $\langle g(x)\rangle$ **is maximal**

In $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, maximal ideals $\iff$ prime ideals